# IDL lambda: Attempt to subscript is out of range

Tags: idl-programming-language

idl 8.4 introduced the [`lambda`](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/LAMBDA.html) function. I have IDL 8.6.1 and the `lambda` function does not fully work as documented:

```
IDL> f = lambda(x : x * x)
IDL> print, call_function(f, findgen(10))
      0.00000      1.00000      4.00000      9.00000      16.0000      25.0000      36.0000      49.0000      64.0000
      81.0000
IDL>  print, f(findgen(10))
IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5 IDL$LAMBDAF5
IDL$LAMBDAF5
IDL> print, f(5)
% Attempt to subscript F with <INT      (       5)> is out of range.
```

So, why `f(5)` does not return `25`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, as commented [here](https://michaelgalloy.com/2014/10/28/idl-8-4-functional-programming.html#comment-754144), this is [documented](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/LAMBDA.html).

> Note: To make direct calls on a Lambda function, you should make sure that compile_opt strictarr (or compile_opt idl2) is turned on so that IDL interprets the parentheses as a function call instead of array indices. See COMPILE_OPT for details.

So
`compile_opt strictarr`
or
`compile_opt idl2`.

However, I would have expected that direct calls are possible by default.